# Get method throwing an error, no idea why

Tags: python, flask

I'm getting the error : `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument`

The entire error is:

```
    [2021-09-04 22:00:53,162] ERROR in app: Exception on /entry/title [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/shakur/PycharmProjects/flaskProject2/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()

  File "/Users/shakur/PycharmProjects/flaskProject2/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)

  File "/Users/shakur/PycharmProjects/flaskProject2/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 467, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/shakur/PycharmProjects/flaskProject2/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 82, in view
    self = view.view_class(*class_args, **class_kwargs)  # type: ignore

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'title'
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Sep/2021 22:00:53] "GET /entry/title HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

For some reason the get request is throwing an error, I'm at a loss on why... no idea. Any suggestions would be appreciated

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "xyz"
api = Api(app)

class Entry(Resource):

    def __init__(self, title, language="Python", attempts=0,wins=0):
        self.title = title
        self.language = language
        self.attempts = attempts
        self.wins = wins


    def __repr__(self):
        #...


    def record_attempts_and_wins(self, a, w=0):
        #...

    @classmethod
    def find_entry_by_title(cls, title):
        connection = sqlite3.connect("data.db")
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        query = "SELECT * FROM entries WHERE title=?"
        result = cursor.execute(query, (title,))
        column = result.fetchone()
        if column:
            entry = cls(*column)
        else:
            entry = None

        connection.close()
        return entry


    def get(self, title):
        entry = Entry.find_entry_by_title(self, title)
        return entry

api.add_resource(Entry, "/entry/<string:title>")
```

Comment: "For some reason the get request is throwing an error, I'm at a loss on why" Your framing is wrong, for the purpose of debugging. If you aren't confident that the request *shouldn't* throw an error, then you really have no understanding of the code at all, and need to take a step back and review. If you do have that confidence, then try to prove it to me, by following through the logic of the code. Show me where the value for the `positional argument: 'title'` is supposed to come from.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the last line should be supplying that arg

Comment: Is it supposed to be inside the class definition?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel no, and its not inside the class definition in my codebase, I only added it so it could be inside of the code block here on stack overflow, I'll try to adjust

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flask doesn't know that you have added positional arguments to the `Resource` subclass. When you call:

```
api.add_resource(Entry, "/entry/<string:title>")
```

it just thinks `Entry` will be a `Resource`, which doesn't have a `title` argument in its constructor. How could it know it needs to pass a `title` when it calls the `Entry()` constructor?

This is addressed in the docs for [passing constructor parameters into resources](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intermediate-usage.html#passing-constructor-parameters-into-resources). You need to tell it what to pass as a title:

```
api.add_resource(Entry, "/entry/<string:title>", resource_class_kwargs={ 'title': "some title" })
```

Comment: I think OP specifically wants to take the `title` to pass from the URL, though?

Comment: That can't work here @KarlKnechtel because this initializes a single resource object that responds to urls with arbitrary `<string:title>` strings. This is created before a single request has been made. You need to deal with the titles in the url in each request. But you're right, maybe the OP didn't know this.

Comment: Okay, so I'm pretty sure the *real* question is *how to do that*. I don't know this framework, but I guess OP already has the appropriate code for that (e.g. `def get(self, title)` etc.) and initializing the `self.title` is redundant and inappropriate.